# What's the fastest barcode reader from PDF in c#

Tags: pdf, sdk, barcode-scanner, itext7, code128

for an application i'm developing, I need a barcode reader. I currently use inlite barcode reader (http://how-to.inliteresearch.com/barcode-reading-howto/) but I would like to know if there is not a faster SDK. because this sdk scan the whole pdf page to find the codes (39 and 128 in my case) and it takes up to 4 hours for a 17238 pdf page.

I know IText7 has a barcode reader too but which one is faster? or if there is another sdk faster, I would like to know.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: PDFsharp does not have a barcode reader.

Comment: Oups sorry, it is IText7. I confused both....

Comment: iText7 does not have a barcode reader.

Comment: ZXing has a barcode reader.

Comment: iText uses part of the ZXing code, but only to generate barcodes, not to read barcodes. And only for QR if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm mistaken again... I thought itextsharp was itext7... The library in NuGet is ITextSharp by Bruno Lowagie, Paulo Saores, et al.  v5.5.11

Comment: iTextSharp is iText 5 for .NET. iText 7 is the successor of the same product.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply run an objective speed-test?
Generate a large number of documents (you can test different codes, different sizes, damage, etc).

Once generated, pull the entire pdf through iText and then through whatever other software suite you have. Time it.

That way you'll get an objective measure of what works best in your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

iText normally is pretty slow, when it comes to big pdfs. I know only commercial solutions, which are fast.
I measured e.g. for a 10.000 pages document, with a lot of content and 117MB in size a barcode detection on all pages in around **334** seconds with the CIB pdf toolbox (https://pdftoolbox.cib.de/). It searched for all barcode types supported. The speed could be improved further, if you specify a region on the pages (e.g. the left border) to search for or to limit the barcode types.
The library is in C++, but has C# bindings.

Internally it utilizes the zxing-cpp barcode reader, which is pretty fast.
https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp